# Python custom Mercurial merge tool in process?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-extension

Given a custom hg merge tool `mymergetool.py`

On Linux, I can do this:

```
merge-tools.MyMergeTool.executable=mymergetool.py
```

which runs the python in a new process.

However on Windows one has to specify python.exe as the executable.
But given that one might not exist on the system (I use hg embedded in an application)

**I would like to be able to do something like this**:

```
merge-tools.MyMergeTool.executable=python:mymergetool.py
```

which runs the merge tool in the same process as hg.

However when reading hg's `filemerge.py` it seems that the `python:` prepend isn't supported in this context.

**Is there any other way of providing a custom merge tool that can run in process?** (eg. using hooks or extensions)

### Reasons why I want to do this

1. I don't want to ship a python.exe with my application. (minor)
2. On some systems, (eg. iOS) it hard to launch external processes, so having a custom merge tool run in process would make things a lot easier.

Comment: It might be easiest to just add this feature to mercurial itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible in Mercurial 4.7 and newer.
[MergeTool configuration documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration)

[(Release Notes)](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Release4.7)

One specifies a python file along with a python function.

```
merge-tools.MyMergeTool.executable=python:mymergetool.py:mergefn
```

The function signature is this:

```
def mergefn(ui, repo, args, **kwargs):
```